# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - can't write unknown attribute Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, associations

So I am still quite new to the rails framework.

I am having problems when build a resource.

I am using an AJAX query to `POST` a JSON array of project_materials to a cart with a line_items association

(I am following the Agile Web Development Book).

This is the error I get
`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError - can't write unknown attribute project_materials_id':`

This is what my controller looks like.
in line_items controller

```
# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json

def create

#materialsArray = params[:materials]
project_id = params[:project_id]
@cart = current_cart
#pm = ProjectMaterials.find(1)
#lm = @cart.line_items.build(:project_materials => pm)
#lm.save
array = JSON::parse(materialsArray)

#puts array

array.each do |key|
  pm = ProjectMaterials.find_by_svg_id(key['id'])
  lm = @cart.line_items.create!(:project_materials => pm)
  lm.save
end

render :js => "window.location = '#{project_path(Project.find(project_id))}'"

end
```

Comment: Please post your table schema & model.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to examine your @cart object and make sure that you have set up accepts_nested_attributes_for line_items in that object.

Answer (score 0):

I made a big mistake. I labelled "project_materials_id" as "project_material_id" in the database.